# How do I sum time differences between "SET" and "RESET" events?

Tags: excel, logging, sum, timestamp, duration

I want to go through my logs and find out how long each output has been on during a specific time period. Pseudo coding it I would find the oldest SET then look for the next RESET entry calculate the duration between the two timestamps and add that time quantity in minutes or decimal hours to a sum then find the next SET and Reset and add that to the sum as well. There will likely be times when there is a RESET event but the SET event is outside my search window and I can ignore those. There will be many different outputs and I want the sum for each distinct "system" and  "code" in the code column as the code contains unit information and the other columns are ancillary.

Example
Time window from 11/15/2015 03:00 to 11/18/2015 03:00

Spreadsheet looks like this:

```
System,Time Stamp,Code,Unit,Event Text,Set/Reset,  
1,11/17/2015 21:41,ABCD,A,Temp is too high,RESET,  
1,11/17/2015 21:39,ABCF,B,Movement is too slow,SET,  
1,11/17/2015 21:41,DCTY,A,Air flow rate is unstable,SET,  
1,11/17/2015 21:44,DCTY,A,Air flow rate is unstable,RESET,  
1,11/17/2015 21:43,ABCF,B,Movement is too slow,RESET,
1,11/17/2015 21:43,CATG,C,Door ajar,SET,
```

When manually crunching the numbers I know Unit B had 4 minutes of code `ABCF` and unit B had 3 minutes of `DCTY`. Unit C's `CATG` has 1 day 13 hours and 45 minutes of set time since it has not yet reset before the end of the window. Also there will most of the time be gaps between the reset and the next set event, so there are two modes: time from set to next reset and reset to next set. I only care about the set to reset duration sums as each set to reset sequence may repeat multiple times. My purpose in seeking these durations is right now I have only been using set event frequency to track issues but an event that is not cleared is not highlighted that way.

Bonus: Can this be done without VBA scripting?

Comment: If not through VBA (VB is something else) then on what platform are you going to do these calculations? Excel Formulas?

Comment: @pnuts yes, all codes may overlap. See updated example CSV

Comment: @nbayly Thank you, I think a VBA script might be the only way I just wanted to see if a formula guru new something that was not so obvious.

Comment: @pnuts thanks for cleaning up the CSV that looks much better. Also why do you keep removing references to excel in the title, isn't that useful information as there are no other references to excel in the question?

Comment: @pnuts Very nice! I forgot about the tags :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that addresses the majority of your requirements. In column `G` starting in `G2` you would place the following Array Formula:

```
=IF(F2="SET",SUM(IF($C:$C=C2,1,0)*IF($F:$F="RESET",1,0)*IF(ISNUMBER($B:$B),$B:$B,0))-B2,"")
```

This is inputted using `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`. Then copied down to all your rows.

Basically it extracts into an array values of 1 for rows that correspond to the same Code and are "RESET" but only for rows that are "SET". It then multiplies these 2 arrays (not matrix multiplication FYI) by the column with the Time Stamps effectively extracting only Time Stamp that confirm to both conditions. Note that as the formula then sums the array this will only be effective if there is only 1 set of SET/RESET for that code. You can add another condition based on the Unit much the same way.

Not a full solution but I hope a starting point.

Comment: Excellent! Your solution does calculate the correct time difference between the 2 complete set-reset pairs, however the logs that I will apply the final solution to do have multiple set-reset pairs for a given code. I think the solution will have to be an iterative script then as it seems from your answer a cell formula approach can only find a single pair as I tried adding a second with different time stamps and the output next to the Set of the 1st and 2nd pair were then both incorrect, but Bonus points for being the first one to show a partial formula based solution! Thanks!